# Find the closed formula for the following sequence $3, 3, 4, 8, 26\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the closed formula for the following sequence$:\quad 3, 3, 4, 8, 26\cdots$

I have been struggling with this one for a while, and am failing to see what I'm missing. It looks like it might be related to Fibonacci's number, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: There exist infinitely many "closed form" for finite term of sequences.

Comment: Ok, but shouldn't there be a formula for $a_n=$?

Comment: Exercise: Find a polynomial $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ such that $p(0)=p(1)=3, p(2)=4, p(3)=8, p(4)=26$. Set your "formula" $a_n := p(n)$. Then, find infinitely many more such polynomials of degree $\ge 5$ going through the same points. Then, realise that questions of this kind make no sense.

Comment: Or to be more playful, for every formula $a_n = ...$ which gives out the above terms, I'll find another one which gives out the same terms, but for higher $n$ will give others: $b_n = a_n + \lfloor \frac{n}{17} \rfloor$. Or $c_n = a_n \cdot (1+ \lfloor \frac{n}{329} \rfloor \cdot \sin(3 e^n - \sqrt{12n\pi}))$.

Comment: For a more constructive criticism: when asking such questions, **always** give the way you *obtain* your sequence. Each member of the sequence must be *defined* (and preferably computable, at least potentially).

Comment: Although such "guess the next number" exercises are often used in intelligence tests, they are NOT math since we only have a "reasonable guess", the author can always have something completely different in mind (excellently illustrated by Torsten, thank you for that!). Therefore , such questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find this sequence starting at $n=20$ in the [OEIS database][1] (sequence A061602).
Basically it is the sum of the factorials of the digits of $n$, so for the case of $n_1=20, n_2=21$, etc., you have:
$$(2!+0!),(2!+1!),(2!+2!),(2!+3!),(2!+4!),...$$
$$=(2+1),(2+1),(2+2),(2+6),(2+24),...$$
$$=3,3,4,8,26$$
[1]: https://oeis.org/A061602

Comment: As pointed out above, this is only one possibility.

Comment: You could at least write this easier as $a_n = n!+2$. So that goes on $3,3,4,8,26, 122, 722, 5042, 40322, 362882, 2628802, 39916802, ...$; of course if you follow that OEIS sequence the search engine found for you, you go on $3,3,4,8,26, 122, 722, 5042, 40322, 362882, 7, 7, 8, ...$. 
But what's wrong with the (e.g. first) formula in my answer, going on $3,3,4,8,26, 78, 193, ...$?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comments: If $a_0=3, a_1=3, a_2=4, a_3=8, a_4=26$, then this is matched by

$$a_n= \frac{1}{24}(9n^4-46n^3+87n^2-50n+72).$$

(If you want to start at index $a_1$ instead of $a_0$, just replace each $n$ in this formula by $n-1$.)

Now this formula gives out $a_5= 78$ as the next term, which is well and nice, but actually, I would like to have a formula $a'_n$ where the next term is $a'_5=18$. Well, fortunately I can add any constant multiple of

$$n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)= n^5-10n^4+35n^3-50n^2+24n$$

to the above formula without changing the terms $a_0, .., a_4$. So with $c:= -\frac{1}{2}$ I get

$$a'_n= \frac{1}{24}(-12n^5+129n^4-466n^3+687n^2-338n+72)$$

which gives me my new favourite sequence $3,3,4,8,26, 18, ...$.

Do you see now why this kind of question makes no sense?